# Null Pointer Exception occurs when i dial my phone

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Manifest:

```
     <receiver  android:name=".CallReceiver">
        <intent-filter  android:priority="100" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

code:

```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      .
      .
      .
  Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
  String incommingNumber = b.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
  if(incommingNumber.length()!=0)
    {. . . . .}
```

NullPointer error goes away if i type

```
      String incommingNumber = "123";
```

any Ideas?

Comment: use Bundle b = getIntent.getExtras();

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem are these lines:

```
String incommingNumber = b.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
  if(incommingNumber.length()!=0)
```

b.getString return null and null.length() throws the error. You need to add a check like this.

```
if (incomingNumber == null) {
  // do something
}
```

This is how getString works:

```
Returns the value associated with the given key, or defaultValue if no mapping of the desired type exists for the given key.
Parameters
key     a String, or null
defaultValue    Value to return if key does not exist
Returns
    a String value, or null
```

-> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29
-> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

Comment: You need to check this case? as mention above. Maybe the function returns null if the number is hidden.